# Meteor iOS app issue with AirWatch VPN Tunneling

Tags: meteor, ionic2, vpn, tunneling, airwatch

We have developed a mobile app using Meteor+Ionic2. We use our internal NodeJS server which is not in internet zone. We got the app deployed to our enterprise app store which enables AirWatch VPN tunneling to get the access to server in intranet zone.

Everything works great when tested with iOS device level using "F5 Access" VPN when deployed using Xcode or enterprise app store with NO VPN tunneling . But when download the app from our enterprise app store which does per-app VPN using AirWatch VPN Tunneling, iOS app gets stuck at the splash screen. It is not seems to call any client side or server side code of Meteor+Ionic2.

When redeploying it using development distribution, It seems to be stays at about:blank and not going to localhost and getting "Failed to load resource" error in about:blank.

The same AirWatch VPN Tunneling works great in Android. This issue seems to be happening only in iOS. I checked device level logs and also AirWatch VPN tunnel logs which donesn't report any errors.

I'm not sure whether Meteor+Ionic2 supports AirWatch VPN Tunneling for iOS as none of framework codes get called. Is there anyway to debug the enterprise distributed app? Is VPN-Tunneling not supported in iOS app development using Meteor?

Thanks,
Annadurai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the issue seems to be AirWatch config which causes the localhost to be appended with domain name like localhost.mycompany.com. As AirWatch couldn't fix this issue, we dropped plan of using AirWatch VPN tunneling.